# Clarification on "Credit-Control-Failure-Handling " AVP

Tags: diameter-protocol

I need clarification on "Credit-Control-Failure-Handling" AVP, and I'd be appreciated if someone can explain about its enumerated values.

So, as I understand if CCFH is in TERMINATE mode (0), and the client doesn't receive CCA within Tx timer period, then the request is regarded as failed and basically session will be terminated.

However, if CCFH is in CONTINUE mode (1), quoted from RFC4006:

> ```
>   When the Credit-Control-Failure-Handling AVP is set to CONTINUE,
>   the credit-control client SHOULD re-send the request to an
>   alternative server in the case of transport or temporary failures,
>   provided that a failover procedure is supported in the credit-
>   control server and the credit-control client, and that an
>   alternative server is available.  Otherwise, the service SHOULD be
>   granted, even if credit-control messages can't be delivered.
> ```

So, my understanding is unlike TERMINATE mode, if the CCA does not answer within Tx timer, the client would provide the service to the end-user.

My question is what if the server actually sends a CCA error message like (DIAMETER_TOO_BUSY or other error messages) within Tx timer to the client. Is the client still provide the service to the end-user or not?

Answer (score 0):

TERMINATE is exactly to terminate.

Later on same doc (or actually - its newer version 8506) says:

> When the Tx timer expires, the Diameter Credit-Control client always
> terminates the service if the CCFH is set to the value TERMINATE.
> The credit-control session may be moved to an alternative server only
> if a protocol error DIAMETER_TOO_BUSY or DIAMETER_UNABLE_TO_DELIVER
> is received before the Tx timer expires.  Therefore, the value
> TERMINATE is not appropriate if proper failover behavior is desired.